# Problem with the CH341 driver in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, usb, 20.04, kernel, arduino

I run into this problem trying to program an ESP8266 board, which uses the CH341 chip in the programming interface as a USB-to-Serial interface. The problem appeared after an upgrade from 19.10 to 20.04 (that I carried out yesterday).

This is the kernel I am using:

```
$ uname -r
5.4.0-58-generic
```

When I connect the ESP8266 board (a Wemos D1 mini) to the USB there is no activity on the syslog (or dmesg), and the kernel module is not loaded. In fact I do not see the /dev/ttyACM0 device in the /dev directory and no useful device appears in the Arduino GUI.

I have found the module in the kernel tree but, even forcing the installation, nothing happens:

```
augusto@Legion:~$ ls /usr/lib/modules/5.4.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/ch*
/usr/lib/modules/5.4.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/ch341.ko
augusto@Legion:~$ sudo modprobe ch341
[sudo] password di augusto: 
augusto@Legion:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05e3:0626 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB3.1 Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:56a6 IMC Networks Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0cf3:e500 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 046d:c517 Logitech, Inc. LX710 Cordless Desktop Laser
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
augusto@Legion:~$ lsmod | grep ch34
ch341                  20480  0
usbserial              53248  1 ch341
```

Without this module it is impossible to work with a relevant number of SBC devices, besides the named Wemos D1 Mini.

Trying to solve the problem I also downloaded the module source from https://github.com/juliagoda/CH341SER and compiled on my PC, but with module signature problems.

If no help is available on this group, I'll appreciate a redirection to a more focused group.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Update: I disabled the "secure boot" feature, compiled and installed the driver by juliagoda, with no relevant result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a false alert, due to the fact that both cables I used were not working properly, one (the one used just after the upgrade) working intermittently. Today I used a third cable and a new Wemos (paranoid you say) for preparing a bug report with apport and the module was loaded and all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem:

I wanted to work with the ESP32 boards from within VirtualBox (guest Ubuntu 21.10). According to kernel config (`` /boot/config-`uname -r` `` ) `ch341` is build as module. But the default Ubuntu installation doesn't install the `` linux-modules-extra-`uname -r` ``  by default.
So installing it solves the device gets attached to `/dev/ttyUSB0`.
Now the ESP32 board can be added as filter in VirtualBox machine settings under USB.